# Angular - How to change workspace name?

Tags: angular, workspace

I was wondering if it's simply changing the name of the workspace folder, or may I need to run some command which will do so, along with updating any config files that the workspace name has changed?

Comment: are you talking about the folder name ? or the package.json name ?

Comment: I want to change the folder name... just want to verify it will not cause problems because there are files that needs to be updated due to the name change.

Comment: you can see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should change the name in `package.json` as well as the folder name. to keep consistency.

Edit: the name in `package.json` should not contain uppercases.

Comment: Sure, I'll change the name there... is it the only file that has the name of the workspace?

Comment: @MightGod yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

please pay attention to your angular.json if you use CLI tools